# Is $\sqrt{(a+b)}\sqrt{(a-b)} = \sqrt{(a^2-b^2)}$?

Tags: calculus

I know that $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ but I wonder if the following also works:

I have $\sqrt{2x+3}$ as homework but I don't know what to do with it; the class hasn't made it this far yet. My first thought would be 
$$\sqrt{a+b}\sqrt{a-b}$$ but I don't know if this will work or not.

Comment: *"I know (a+b)(a-b)=a^2+b^2"* - No, it's wrong, there should be minus.

Comment: I bit of mistake sorry and thanks :D

Answer (score 7):

No.

Suppose
$a=-2, b=0$.

It is true if
$a \ge b \ge 0$.

Comment: It is also true if $a\ge 0 \ge b \ge -a$. Actually, all square roots are defined iff  $a\ge |b|$.

Answer (score 1):

note that $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$ since we have $$a\geq -b$$ and $$a\geq b$$ we have
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)\geq 0$$ and your Statement is true.